# Show a loader while a Meteor CollectionFS and S3 image downloads?

Tags: amazon-s3, meteor

Is there any function/hook for showing a loader while an Amazon S3 image downloads from Amazon S3 (or any image from anywhere for that matter)?  I'm not currently using any CDNs or CloudFront, so my downloads can sometimes be slow.  I'd like to just show a loader while the image is downloading.  In my code I have:

```
{{#if uploadedCustomLogo}}
   {{#with customLogo}}
      {{#if isUploaded}}
         <div class="img-wrapper">
            <img src="{{this.url store='logos'}}" alt=""/>
         </div>
      {{else}}
         {{> loading}}
      {{/if}}
   {{/with}} 
{{/if}}
```

The issue is the uploading `{{> loading }}` loader-template runs fine, but it only lasts a fraction of a second because the actual upload is really fast.  It's the download that can then take several seconds (sometimes up to twenty or so even on a small image).  Is there any way to test/check if an image has been downloaded?

I used FF Inspector to see if there was a delay in the `src` getting set on the `img` tag but it gets set immediately.  So the wait is really on S3... nothing changes in the DOM once it finally loads.

I'm using CollectionFS and the S3 adapter (Meteor-cfs-s3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  I was searching for the wrong thing on Google.  The question is really how to use JQuery to listen for when an image has loaded.  So you can just add your loader in your template, then hide it once the `load` event fires on the image. This simple code works great in Meteor:

```
Template.myTemplate.events({

   'load #whateverImage': function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      //  Hide your loader DIV (for example)
      hideLoader();
},
```

Comment: The only problem I still have is in Firefox, any cached image will show correctly in the browser and then fire it's load event once it reloads from S3 (which seems weird, not sure why a cached image reloads itself.)  So this creates a problem because if I show a loader until the load-event fires, on cached images, the image will show along with the loader. So for now I'm just showing a loader on the first upload/showing of an image before it gets cached.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use has stored helper, I also had a problem figuring this one out isUploaded is to the meteor server but if you want to wait to for it to be uploaded to amazon s3 `{{#if this.hasStored 'thumbs'}}`

**edit:** 
Here is my custom helper to check if it's upload & stored to amazon s3 (So I can safely create an amazon s3 url and display it to the user).

Which in my case looks like this:

```
uploadDoc: function () {
  var fileId = Template.instance().posterData.get('fileId'); // You can ignore this, It's just how I get the file document id.
  if (fileId)
    return Images.findOne(fileId); // We need the file document
}

isUploadedAndStored: function (storage) {
  if (this && this.copies && this.copies[storage])
    return true;
}

sUrl: function () {
  if (this && this.copies && this.copies.thumbs)
    return 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/NAME/' + this.copies.thumbs.key;
}
```

using it like this:

```
{{#with uploadDoc}}
  {{#if isUploadedAndStored 'thumbs'}}
    <img class="attachment-thumbnail" src="{{sUrl}}">
  {{else}}
    {{>loading}}
  {{/if}}
{{/with}}
```

How it works? When we subscribe to the uploaded file collection the document will not have `copies` and when it comes from the server it means it's actually saved on amazon s3, the `this.hasStored` does similar check but I found it to re-run too many times maybe need to report it to github so they can fix it.

Comment: Have you had any luck enabling AWS CloudFront with cfs:s3? I can't get it to work.  I updating my IAM user with a CloudFront policy and I set `endpoint` to my CloudFront endpoint in my `FS.Store.S3` objects (this is a parameter they can accept).  But the images never download. CloudFront is supposed to just pass through the images - as long as the permissions are set right.

Comment: About CloudFront, it's easy enough to do if you have your `ACL` set to `public-read`, then you can just build the URL for your `<img>` tags using your CloudFront URL and the `copies.collectionName.key` property from your image collection.  Still working on signed requests.

Comment: In response to your answer... I can't get `{{#if this.hasStored 'store'}}` to ever return true. I have it inside my `{{#with customLogo}}` and it never returns true.  I can get `this.isUploaded` to return something, but it always returns super-quick.  The longest time to wait it seems is still for the image to download.  Unless it's storing and for some reason I can't get `this.hasStored` to do anything.

Comment: @evolross I didn't use cloudfront, just s3. That's weird that this.hasStored doesn't work for you, You might have wrong config like 'store' is it the correct name? I actually started using my own helper because it seems `this.hasStored` called multiple times. I will update my answer with it

Comment: It turns out I was doing something slightly wrong...  I fixed it and now `isUploaded` and `hasStored` are working! **Still** some issues I have is now I can use `uploadProgress` and see the number change from 0 to 100 (esp on big files), but it still goes to 100% and hangs for many seconds. It's taking time to "store" and then "download".  We need a `storeProgress`.  Same with deleting a file, it sometimes takes many seconds for the callback to run after a `Images.remove(id)`.  I wish there was a `removeProgess` too.  Do you see this at all? Most images upload quick and take a while to store.